# Logs in pyspark code that are embedded into lazy evaluatoin and execute when the lazy is executed

Tags: python, pyspark

I am struggling to find a way to implement logs into my pyspark code whereby they execute when a commands such as count is called.

```
df = SparkDataframe
df = function1(df)
logger.info("function 1 complete")
df = function2(df)
logger.info("function 2 complete")
df.count()
```

these functions will be lazy evaluated and a lazy plan for df created until the count is called.

Is there a way to have log outputs part of the lazy evaluation so that they will execute when the count execution reaches them in its lazy plan.

Currently all my logs execute when the cell is first run and don't reexecute during the count operation as i imagine they are no part of the lazy code as they don't link to the df.

this code will send logs to the Log4j output however it will execute when the code is lazy evaluated and not when a .count() or .show() is run which is what i want as i essentially want to debug the pipeline.

```
log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
LOGGER = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.info("pyspark script logger initialized")
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want to see over here? You can always view the driver logs to see what is going on during the actual evaluations

Comment: I'm looking for a line by line log output, the driver logs don't give a granular enough approach. The code will get stuck at a point and it becomes increasingly difficult to understand where exactly in the code it is stuck.